# Migrating to DynamicSupervisor from Supervisor Elixir

Tags: elixir

I am trying to upgrade to `DynamicSupervisor` from `Supervisor`.

I have this simple supervisor,

```
  use Supervisor
  alias EvercamMedia.Snapshot.Worker

  def start_link() do
    Supervisor.start_link(__MODULE__, :ok, name: __MODULE__)
  end

  def init(:ok) do
    children = [worker(Worker, [], restart: :permanent)]
    supervise(children, strategy: :simple_one_for_one, max_restarts: 1_000_000)
  end

  def start_child(settings) do
    Supervisor.start_child(__MODULE__, [settings])
  end
```

I converted it into this

```
use DynamicSupervisor
alias EvercamMedia.Snapshot.Worker

def start_link() do
  DynamicSupervisor.start_link(__MODULE__, :ok, name: __MODULE__)
end

def init(:ok) do
  spec = %{id: Worker, start: {Worker, :start_link, []}}
  DynamicSupervisor.init(spec, strategy: :simple_one_for_one, max_restarts: 1_000_000)
end

def start_child(settings) do
  DynamicSupervisor.start_child(__MODULE__, [settings])
end
```

But its giving me an error as

```
    ** (UndefinedFunctionError) function DynamicSupervisor.init/2 is undefined or private
        (elixir 1.10.0) DynamicSupervisor.init(%{id: EvercamMedia.Snapshot.Worker, start: {EvercamMedia.Snapshot.Worker, :start_link, []}}, [strategy: :simple_one_for_one, max_restarts: 1000000])
        (elixir 1.10.0) lib/dynamic_supervisor.ex:541: DynamicSupervisor.init/1
```

Anyhelp would be thankful, about this issue, Also , I want to know if the above Supervisor implementation make sense ? to have just an `ok` in init?

Answer (score 0):

In this line,

```
DynamicSupervisor.init(spec, strategy: :simple_one_for_one, max_restarts: 1_000_000)
```

`strategy` and `max_restart` should be defined inside the `app.ex` children's. 
The spec should be used here, but only on `start_child/1`.

When I've implemented a DynamicSupervisor this was my code:

```
children = [ ..., 
  {MyApp.Supervisor, strategy: :one_for:one} // MyApp.Supervisor implements DynamicSupervisor.
]
```

Then in that class:

```
def init(args) do
  DynamicSupervisor.init(arg)
end
```